# Why am I getting an error when declaring a variable in a class declaration within a header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a class that has a simple integer with in it. Of course, it uses header files and whatnot.

Here's the code:

class.h

```
 class consolBuf
{
private:
    int buffersize1 = 10; //Data member initializer is not allowed
    int buffersize2 = 10;
    static char screenBuffer[10][10]; //screenBuffer
public:
    consolBuf(void);
    ~consolBuf(void);
    void draw();
    void write(int x, int y);
    char get(int x, int y);
};
```

For some reason some reson Visual Studio keeps complaining that I can't declare a integer in the class.h. I've searched everywhere and I can't find an answer. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Who told you that it **should** be possible?

Comment: @KerrekSB It "should" be possible because the current C++ standard allows it. It isn't possible because the current C++ standard is fairly new and to the best of my knowledge, no complete implementation exists at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can't initialize members like that. If you wanted to initialize those as default values for each instance, you would do that in the constructor:

```
consolBuf::consolBuf()
    : buffersize1(10)
    , buffersize2(10)
{

}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted, the reason I needed variable is because I wanted people to be able to change the buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03, only static constant values can be defined inside the class. But then, it seems that this is what you need anyway in your case:

```
class consolBuf
{
private:
    static int const buffersize1 = 10; //Data member initializer is now allowed
    static int const buffersize2 = 10;
    static char screenBuffer[buffersize1][buffersize2]; //screenBuffer
public:
    consolBuf(void);
    ~consolBuf(void);
    void draw();
    void write(int x, int y);
    char get(int x, int y);
};
```

Note that in C++11, your original code is allowed. So if your original code is really what you wanted, all you might have to do is to enable C++11 features. In C++03, you'll have to use member inizializers in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize *fixed values*, declare `buffersize1` and `buffersize2` as being `static const`. Otherwise if you want the variables to be local to each instance of a class, initialize them in the constructor.

Apparently C++0x/C++11 allows your above code, however I'd *personally* still prefer instance variables to be initialized all together in a constructor.